# Mirror multiplayer player color update not showing on other clients

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

The code below is on the player and successfully updates the color of the several materials used for this player. This is called during the game to change the color after spawn and called again to change the player back to the original color.

```
 [Command]
 public void CmdHandlePlayerColorChange(Color newColor)
 {
     foreach (MeshRenderer mr in meshes)
     {
         currColor = newColor;
         mr.material.color = currColor;
     }
 }
```

However, the other clients do not pickup the color change (the color stays the same as set at spawntime). I tried Command/ClientRpc (below), but this crashed the other client.

```
 [ClientRpc]
 void RpcPlayerColorChange(Color newColor)
 {
     foreach (MeshRenderer mr in meshes)
     {
         currColor = newColor;
         mr.material.color = currColor;
     }
 }
 [Command]
 public void CmdHandlePlayerColorChange(Color newColor)
 {
     RpcPlayerColorChange(newColor);
 }
```

I appreciate any suggestions to get the other clients to pick up the color change.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `crashed the other client`? In the code I see nothing obvious wrong (except why assign `currColor` within the loop?) .. afaik it should work assuming that `meshes` is Initialized on all players

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for your response. The player is composed of multiple renderers. meshes is declared as: 
     private MeshRenderer[] meshes;
And value is set in Start():
     meshes = player.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();

Comment: I looked at the crash again after your response. It is a nullreference exception on the non-changing client which makes sense as the client needs access to mesh on the other player.
When attempting to pass meshes to RpcPlayerColorChange, the following error is generated:
     Cannot generate writer for component type MeshRenderer. Use a supported type or provide a custom writer (at UnityEngine.MeshRenderer)

Comment: Yeah no you can't sent MonoBehaviour references via networking the other side wouldn't know what to do with that information .. simply make sure the `Start` is actually called on the clients before the RPC is called